# ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Airbrake (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, production-environment, airbrake

I'm working on a rails 3.2.8 project, I've just installed the airbrake gem to track errors, In development I did the airbrake installation steps, then when I did the deployment with capistrano, I got the following error in the unicorn production log:

```
E, [2012-10-16T03:02:51.588084 #3645] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 3846 exit 1> worker=3
I, [2012-10-16T03:02:51.588434 #3645]  INFO -- : worker=3 spawning...
I, [2012-10-16T03:02:51.708539 #3858]  INFO -- : worker=3 spawned pid=3858
I, [2012-10-16T03:02:51.708986 #3858]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2012-10-16T03:02:52.793217 #3849] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Airbrake (NameError)
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/releases/20121011033552/config/initializers/airbrake.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/releases/20121011033552/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:4:in `require'
config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:696:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:696:in `build_app!'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:569:in `init_worker_process'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:589:in `worker_loop'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:487:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:498:in `maintain_worker_count'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:272:in `join'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/apps/nimrod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `<main>'
```

I've noticed the airbrake gem is installed in shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems with all other gems.

In production I'm running a Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with unicorn running with nginx and ruby 1.9.3-p194, with this gems

```
Using airbrake (3.1.4) 
Using capistrano (2.12.0)    
Using bundler (1.1.4) 
Using rails (3.2.8) 
Using unicorn (4.3.1)
```

And also tried to stop nginx, unicorn and then start them all again, but it didn't worked

I hope someone can help me with this

Comment: Did you find a solution? I just hit the same issue, and my setup looks nearly identical.

Comment: Not really, I redeploy the app in other VPS instance and it simply worked... I guess it is an issue with the Unicorn restart process, It didn't loaded correctly the dependencies, but no final solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error after updating my bundle.

It seems like you have to require rake_handler in your airbrake initializer (config/initializers/airbrake.rb or config/initializers/errbit.rb):

```
require 'airbrake/rake_handler'
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to knagode above. I needed to add the rake handler.

```
require 'airbrake/rake_handler'
```

I also needed to stop and start the server again.

```
cap <env> deploy:stop
cap <env> deploy:start
```

It didn't seem that the restart functionality picked it up.

My stack:

- Nginx
- Unicorn
- Rails 4
- Sidekiq
- Redis
- Postgres

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting the server this way helped:

```
cap <env> deploy:stop
cap <env> deploy:start
```